# How to send websocket event asynchronously using ws-rs?

Tags: rust

Using the [ws-rs library](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs), how do I send a websocket message asynchronously?

In the examples I see `on_message` being used to *reply* to a message but how would a server send a message out of the blue?

For example:

- Client sends request to start processing data
- Server responds using `on_message` with "yes I am starting to process your data"
- Every 1% change server responds with an update

In my case processing takes a long time and should report data in the meantime the user is going to be playing with while data is being processed so I really want the server to report the progress data while processing.

If I do that in the `on_message`, it simply responds with a message at the end of processing which defeats the purpose of using websockets. [See related issue on github](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/issues/271).

I am open to switching the websocket library if there is another one that is simpler to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from the [server example](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/blob/master/examples/server.rs):

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time;

use ws::listen;

fn main() {
    listen("127.0.0.1:3012", |out| {
        let out2 = out.clone();

        // Periodic
        thread::spawn(move || loop {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
            if let Err(e) = out2.send(format!("{:?}", time::Instant::now())) {
                println!("Error sending a periodic message: {:?}", e);
            }
        });

        // Echo
        move |msg| {
            println!("Server got message {:?}. ", msg);
            out.send(msg)
        }
    })
    .expect("Failed to create a websocket server");
}
```

`listen` gives you `Sender` (called `out` here) and expects you to return a closure that is executed whenever the server receives a message.

However, you can clone the sender (`out2`), move it to another thread and send messages independently of client.

Testing via websocat:

```
$ websocat ws://localhost:3012
Instant { tv_sec: 1303759, tv_nsec: 406805996 }
Instant { tv_sec: 1303760, tv_nsec: 407008101 }
abc     # <--- what I sent
abc
Instant { tv_sec: 1303761, tv_nsec: 407154068 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll test it out and accept the answer later today.